# RewriteRule for multiple subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I can't seem to find an answer to this problem.

I have a site with many languages with a subdirectory structure. Now I need to redirect them automatically from index.htm to /

e.g.

```
agb-german/index.htm -> agb-german/
agb-english/index.htm -> agb-english/
```

of course I could just create a redirect for each language but I think a rewriterule would do a much better job also for the performance.

So I need something like

```
RewriteRule ^agb-(.*)/index.(.*)$ /agb-{how-to-get-this-from-the-request?}/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /agb- [NC]
RewriteRule ^(agb-\w+)/index\. /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

We are matching `agb-\w+` from input URL and using parentheses `(...)` we capture matched value in `$1`.

Comment: What if I need it the other way round, so that everything behind agb-english leads to agb-english/index.htm ?

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /agb- [NC]
RewriteRule ^(agb-\w+)\. /$1/index.htm [R=301,L,NC]

Comment: Can you tell me with an example what rewrite rule you need?